# Expresión regular con todos los componentes opcionales ¿Cómo evitar capturas vacías?

Tags: c++, regex

Debo procesar una cadena de valores separados por comas que contiene tripletes de valores y traducir en tiempo de ejecución cada triplete a diferentes tipos según su contenido, los datos de entrada serían parecidos a:

```
"1x2y3z,80r160g255b,48h30m50s,1x3z,255b,1h,..."
```

Así que cada sub-cadena debería ser procesada de la siguiente manera:

- `1x2y3z` se procesaría como `Vector3` con `x = 1`, `y = 2` y `z = 3`.
- `80r160g255b` se procesaría como `Color` con `r = 80`, `g = 160` y `b = 255`.
- `48h30m50s` se procesaría como `Time` con `h = 48`, `m = 30` y `s = 50`.

El problema que me encuentro es que cada componente es opcional (aunque siempre aparece en el mismo orden) así que las siguientes cadenas también son `Vector3`, `Color` y `Time` correctos:

- `1x3z` se procesaría como `Vector3` con `x = 1`, `y = 0` y `z = 3`.
- `255b` se procesaría como `Color` con `r = 0`, `g = 0` y `b = 255`.
- `1h` se procesaría como `Time` con `h = 1`, `m = 0` y `s = 0`.

¿Qué he intentado hasta ahora?

#### Todos los componentes como opcionales.

```
((?:\d+A)?(?:\d+B)?(?:\d+C)?)
```

Los caracteres `A`, `B` y `C` serían reemplazados por la letra correcta en cada caso. Esta expresión funciona bien salvo por el hecho de que captura el doble de resultados esperados (uno para la cadena buscada y otra captura con una cadena vacía justo después de la primera coincidencia), por ejemplo:

- `1h1m1s` dos coincidencias:

  1. `"1h1m1s"`.
  2. `""`.
- `11x50z` dos coincidencias:

  1. `"11x50z"`.
  2. `""`.
- `11111h` dos coincidencias:

  1. `"11111h"`.
  2. `""`.

No puedo decir que no lo esperara... al fin y al cabo una cadena vacía se corresponde con la expresión regular proporcionada cuando todos los componentes están vacíos; así que para solucionar este problema intenté lo siguiente:

#### Cuantificador de 1 a 3 elementos.

```
((?:\d+[ABC]){1,3})
```

Pero con esta expresión, se capturan cadenas con el orden incorrecto o incluso con elementos repetidos:

- `1s1m1h` una coincidencia, no debería coincidir (orden incorrecto).
- `11z50z` una coincidencia, no debería coincidir (componentes repetidos).
- `1r1r1b` una coincidencia, no debería coincidir (componentes repetidos).

Así que hice otro intento con una versión modificada de mi primer intento:

#### Coincidir de inicio `^` a fin `$` de la cadena.

```
^((?:\d+A)?(?:\d+B)?(?:\d+C)?)$
```

Funciona mejor que la primera versión pero sigue coincidiendo con cadenas vacías, con la desventaja añadida que primero debo separar la cadena por cada coma (`,`) y pasar la expresión sobre cada sub-cadena.

#### Usando Lookahead

El intento usando Lookahead:

```
\b(?=[^,])(?=.)((?:\d+A)?(?:\d+B)?(?:\d+C)?)\b
```

Contra la siguiente cadena:

```
"48h30m50s,1h,1h1m1s,11111h,1s1m1h,1h1h1h,1s,1m,1443s,adfank,12322134445688,48h"
```

Los resultados son muy buenos, detecta las coincidencias válidas sin añadir falsos positivos. Por desgracia, cada vez que se encuentra una cadena que no coincide con la expresión, añade una cadena vacía justo antes de la cadena no válida (encuentra `""` antes de `"1s1m1h"`, `"1h1h1h"`, `"adfank"` y `"12322134445688"`) así que he hecho un último intento modificando la condición del Lookahead:

```
\b(?=(?:\d+[ABC]){1,3})(?=.)((?:\d+A)?(?:\d+B)?(?:\d+C)?)\b
```

Esta expresión elimina las cadenas vacías detectadas antes de cualquier cadena que no coincida con `(?:\d+[ABC]){1,3})` (las cadenas vacías antes de `"adfank"` y `"12322134445688"`) pero las cadenas vacías antes de `"1s1m1h"`, `"1h1h1h"` aún son detectadas.

---

Así que mi pregunta es: ¿Existe alguna expresión regular que encuentre coincidencias en tripletes de valores en un orden determinado, sin repeticiones, con todos los componentes opcionales pero compuesta por al menos un elemento y que no halle coincidencias en cadenas vacías?

La herramienta de expresiones regulares que estoy usando es `<regex>` de [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partamos de la expresión donde cada una de las tres magnitudes son opcionales

```
(?:\d+A)?(?:\d+B)?(?:\d+C)?
```

**1. Anclar al inicio de un valor**

Para garantizar que un valor comience en el inicio del texto o en una coma, agregamos las dos opciones al principio.

```
(?:^|,)(?:\d+A)?(?:\d+B)?(?:\d+C)?
^^^^^^^
```

**2. Evitar coincidencias vacías**

Tal cual mostraste en tu último intento, se puede utilizar una aserción positiva ([*positive lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) para garantizar que haya algún caracter antes de la coma, sin consumir este caracter dentro de la coincidencia global. Nos basta con verificar que haya al menos 1 dígito (`\d`).

```
(?:^|,)(?=\d)(?:\d+A)?(?:\d+B)?(?:\d+C)?
       ^^^^^^
```

**3. Que sólo coincida si cumple con todo el patrón**

Ahora bien, como mencionaste en tu última observación, un patrón de este estilo podría coincidir con el lookahead, pero luego coincidir con una cadena vacía. Para eso, agregaremos que al final deba coincidir con una coma o el final del string. En este caso, utilizamos otra aserción, de modo que no consuma la siguiente coma (y esté disponible para una próxima coincidencia).

```
(?:^|,)(?=\d)(?:\d+A)?(?:\d+B)?(?:\d+C)?(?=,|$)
                                        ^^^^^^^
```

<kbd>[Demo en regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/F1j9WN/1)</kbd>

**4. Capturar números y unidades por separado**

Por un tema de practicidad, nos conviene utilizar [grupos](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (*entre paréntesis*) para capturar cada uno de los valores por separado.

```
(?:^|,)(?=\d)(?:(\d+)(A))?(?:(\d+)(B))?(?:(\d+)(C))?(?=,|$)
                ^   ^^ ^     ^   ^^ ^     ^   ^^ ^
```

<kbd>[Demo en regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/F1j9WN/2)</kbd>

#### Código

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string texto("48A30B50C,1A,1A1B1C,11111A,1C1B1A,1A1A1A,1C,1B,1443C,adfank,12322134445688,48A");
    regex patron(R"/((?:^|,)(?=\d)(?:(\d+)(A))?(?:(\d+)(B))?(?:(\d+)(C))?(?=,|$))/");

    //Iterar cada una de las coincidencias
    sregex_iterator next(texto.begin(), texto.end(), patron);
    sregex_iterator end;
    while (next != end) {
        smatch match = *next;

        //Coincidencia global (incluye la coma)
        cout << "Valor: " << match.str() << endl;

        //Iterar cada uno de los grupos (saltando de a 2)
        for( int grupo = 1; grupo < match.size(); grupo += 2 ) {
            string numero = match[grupo];
            string letra  = match[grupo+1];

            //Está el grupo o devolvió una cadena vacía por ser opcional?
            if (!letra.empty()) {
                cout << "\tNúmero: " << numero << endl
                     << "\tLetra:  " << letra  << endl;
            }
        }
        next++;
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Valor: 48A30B50C
    Número: 48
    Letra:  A
    Número: 30
    Letra:  B
    Número: 50
    Letra:  C
Valor: ,1A
    Número: 1
    Letra:  A
Valor: ,1A1B1C
    Número: 1
    Letra:  A
    Número: 1
    Letra:  B
    Número: 1
    Letra:  C
Valor: ,11111A
    Número: 11111
    Letra:  A
Valor: ,1C
    Número: 1
    Letra:  C
Valor: ,1B
    Número: 1
    Letra:  B
Valor: ,1443C
    Número: 1443
    Letra:  C
Valor: ,48A
    Número: 48
    Letra:  A
```

<kbd>[Demo en ideone.com](http://ideone.com/EM0uSI)</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Cojamos uno de los tres posibles grupos ya que la solución debería ser posteriormente extensible:

```
1x2y3z
```

Que esquematizado quedaría:

```
\d+x\d+y\d+z
```

Ahora bien, cada uno de estos tres grupos es opcional aunque para evitar falsos positivos debemos asumir que **al menos uno** va a estar presente siempre. Es decir, el grupo deberá contener **al menos** `\d+x` o `\d+y` o `\d+z`. Esta asunción tiene ciertas implicaciones:

- Si el grupo empieza por `\d+x` es posible que encontremos `\d+y` y `\d+z`
- Si el grupo empieza por `\d+y` es posible que encontremos `\d+z` pero nunca encontraremos `\d+x`
- Si el grupo empieza por `\d+z` no podremos encontrar ni `\d+x` ni `\d+y`

Esto llevado a la expresión regular quedaría así:

```
(\d+x(?:\d+y)?(?:\d+z)?|\d+y(?:\d+z)?|\d+z)
```

Esta solución evita recuperar cadenas vacías ya que siempre fuerza a que haya al menos un elemento.

A raiz de una conversación en el chat con @Mariano, otra opción:

```
(\d+[xyz][^,]*)
```

Esta solo estaría indicada si puedes garantizar que los datos recibidos son correctos, ya que se comería, por ejemplo `1x2345abracadabra`, pero desde luego debería ser más rápida.

La expresión anterior se podría ampliar para ser un poco menos tolerante:

```
((?:\d+[xyz]){1,3})
```